# How to query data stored into JavaRDD<java.class>?

Tags: java, bigdata, apache-spark

I've written a simple java class called Person.java to create Person Object.

e.g:

```
public Person(){
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

I then implemented below code in Apache Spark main driver class.

```
JavaRDD<Person> people = ctx.textFile(logFile).map(
            new Function<String, Person>() {
                public Person call(String line) throws Exception {
                    String[] parts = line.split("\\|");

                    Person trans = new Person();
                    trans.setName(parts[0]);

                    return trans;
                }
            });
```

> > > Above functions compiles and run fine But the problem is I'm not sure how to query the people dataset. How do i get the stored data?

when I tried:
    people.first();

the output was:
   Person@3f03a49

which i assume the problem with casting? How do i convert it to human readable?

Comment: Why do you think that the object you have is not what you want? You did not define `toString()`, but are saying you don't know what to make of its default string representation.

Comment: Thank you Sean for your prompt reply. I tried the toString() prior to posting this post but no joy. I definitely want create and use the Person object but once I've stored the data into RDD, not sure how to inspect those data within the RDD. 

I'm able to query below 'test' object without any issues as it's String but not the case for Person.
    `JavaRDD<String> test = ctx.textFile(file://...)`

Comment: What do you mean? Everything you write suggests you have the Person object exactly as you want.

Comment: Thanks Sean for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend learning some Java in general before trying to work with a complex library like Spark. `Person@3f03a49` is not a problem with casting, this is how an object of class `Person` is converted to a `String` by default. You just need to define

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person(" + name + ")";
}
```

inside `Person` class.

> How do i get the stored data?

With any [actions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/scala-programming-guide.html#actions): `first`, `collect`, etc. But note that by default Spark doesn't *store* data, it's computed on the fly.